# Construct a System.Type for a generic interface with known type of T

Tags: c#, reflection, inversion-of-control

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**

I have an interface definition `IFoo<TBar> : IFoo` and a method `CreateFooUsingBarType(Type barType)`. I need the method to resolve an `IFoo<TBar>` using a dependency injection tool given a specified `System.Type` **instance** that defines `TBar`. Don't ask how I ended up here. I am stuck within these boundaries.

**EXAMPLE**

```
public IFoo CreateFooUsingBarType(Type barType)
{
    var iocScope = GetScope();

    // TODO: Create a System.Type for IFoo<TBar>
    // where TBar is barType. Blarghity blargh.
    var fooType =  (Type)null;

    return iocScope.Resolve(fooType);
}
```

I've tried mucking around with [TypeBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) but I'm getting the sense that it's overkill for this. Does .NET expose a different API for achieving this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [MakeGenericType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) method:

```
var fooType = typeof(IFoo<>).MakeGenericType(barType);
```

Comment: Doh! So simple. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the `<>` is required to refer to `IFoo<T>` rather than `IFoo`.