# Creating generic type with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm studying C# at my university and I have to create an generic class instance with reflection, but I don't know how to do it exactly. Here's my code:

```
public class MyClass <A, B>
{
    protected A a;
    protected B b;
    public MyClass(A a, B b) { this.a = a; this.b = b; }
}
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type typ = typeof(MyClass<int, int>);
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typ);

    }
```

And my question is: how can I pass parameters to constructor and initialize the fields using typeof (something like MyClass c= new MyClass(4, 6); without using reflection)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Construct a System.Type for a generic interface with known type of T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49467951/construct-a-system-type-for-a-generic-interface-with-known-type-of-t)

Comment: If you are asking how to provide your constructor with arguments when creating the object, then this can be done by `Activator.CreateInstance(typ, new object[] { 4, 6 })` or `Activator.CreateInstance(typ, 4, 6)`.

Comment: Yes, that is the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to write

```
typeof(MyClass<,>).MakeGenericType(type, otherType);
```

`typeof(MyClass<,>)` returns an *open generic type* that does not specify parameters.  `MakeGenericType()` then creates from that a *closed (or concrete) generic type*, which does specify parameters.

Comment: You still do C#, When your day life is in Javascript?